# c#/WPF openFileDialog box opens twice

Tags: c#, wpf

When I click the button to open a file the `OpenFileDialog` box opens twice. The first box only opens the image files and the second box text files. If the user decides to close out the first box without choosing a file the second box pops up as well. I'm not sure what I am over looking on this issue. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

```
OpenFileDialog of = new OpenFileDialog();   
of.Filter = "All Image Formats|*.jpg;*.png;*.bmp;*.gif;*.ico;*.txt|JPG Image|*.jpg|BMP image|*.bmp|PNG image|*.png|GIF Image|*.gif|Icon|*.ico|Text File|*.txt";

if (of.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
{
try
{
   image1.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(of.FileName));

    // enable the buttons to function (previous page, next page, rotate left/right, zoom in/out)
    button1.IsEnabled = false;
    button2.IsEnabled = false;
    button3.IsEnabled = false;
    button4.IsEnabled = false;
    button5.IsEnabled = true;
    button6.IsEnabled = true;
    button7.IsEnabled = true;
    button8.IsEnabled = true;                          
}
catch (ArgumentException)
{
    // Show messagebox when argument exception arises, when user tries to open corrupted file
    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Invalid File");
}
 }
 else if(of.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
 {
try
{
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(of.FileName))
    {
        textBox2.Text = sr.ReadToEnd();
        button1.IsEnabled = true;
        button2.IsEnabled = true;
        button3.IsEnabled = true;
        button4.IsEnabled = true;
        button5.IsEnabled = true;
        button6.IsEnabled = true;
        button7.IsEnabled = true;
        button8.IsEnabled = true;

    }
}
catch (ArgumentException)
{
    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Invalid File");
}
}
```

Comment: That is because the first if is false, then it evaluates the 2nd if statement. Sounds like this method is doing several things, i would suggest refactoring and calling the ShowDialogs() in seperate methods.

Comment: I cannot tell what you are trying to accomplish...what is the purpose of opening two dialog boxes? It appears as if you can choose a text file both times.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: My apologies about the title.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're calling `ShowDialog()` twice:

```
if (of.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
    {
       //...
    }
    else if(of.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
```

Just call it once, and save the results:

```
var dialogResult = of.ShowDialog();
if (dialogResult == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
{
       //...
}
// Note that the condition was the same!
else if(dialogResult != System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
```

---

Edit:

If you want the second dialog to only show when the first is handled, you can do:

```
var dialogResult = of.ShowDialog();
if (dialogResult == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
{
       //...

    // Do second case here -  Setup new options
    dialogResult = of.ShowDialog(); //Handle text file here
}
```

Comment: The `if` and `else if` statements have the same condition.

Comment: @AbZy Yeah - that was in the original too... will note that

Comment: `The first box only opens the image files and the second box text files` .the OP most likely wanted two different `OpenFileDialog` objects to open for each type. That's why he used the OK twice (Maybe)

Comment: The objective for this simple application was to allow the user to load any image file or text file into a viewer. If an image was displayed I only wanted certain buttons to be usable for the user and likewise for text files.

Comment: For some reason I am unable to properly load the text files. However the image files load fine.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `ShowDialog` both in the `if` and `else if` condition. That method is responsible for showing the dialog and only has the nice side effect of also telling you what the user clicked.

Store the method's result in a variable and check that in your if..elseif conditions instead.